# Color picker wont change background color from RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android

I have an app where the user can use a color picker or pre-defined buttons to change the background of their quotes. I want to make it possible that the user can change the color of the predefined buttons with a longclick and then a color picker appears and the user can now choose to save any color to the button.

For some reason the color pickers listener methods dosn't work in my `RecyclerView` adapter. The color picker listener should give me the current seleceted color. I have tested it with a `Log.d("TAG", ""+color);`
and I dont get any values

**The RecyclerView adapater's Viewholder for background colors:**

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, ColorPickerDialogFrag2.ColorPickerDialogListener {

    public ImageButton colorButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.colorButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorbutton);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        MainActivity.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((mColorButtons.get(position).getColor())));
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.getAppContext()).edit().putInt(App.BACKGROUND, Color.parseColor(mColorButtons.get(position).getColor())).apply();


    //ColorPicker for customizing colors for buttons

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


        ColorPickerDialogFrag2 cp = ColorPickerDialogFrag2.newInstance(6, Color.YELLOW);
        cp.setStyle(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);
        cp.show(fragmentManager,"d");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewColorChanged(int dialogId, int color) {

        //color is the current color from the colorpicker

            Log.d("TAG", ""+color);
            MainActivity.mEditText.setBackgroundColor(color);




    }

    @Override
    public void onColorSelected(int dialogId, int color) {
        Log.d("TAG", ""+color);
        MainActivity.mEditText.setBackgroundColor(color);

    }
}
```

**Here is an video of how it currently works in my app:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpYjKMLd9aU

The Color Picker libray I use is this: https://github.com/danielnilsson9/color-picker-view

Comment: What are you using to create your `ColorPickerDialogFrag2`? Is it a library or your own custom class?

Comment: @Bryan oh its a library. I will metion that with a link to it now.

Comment: Can you post your `ColorPickerDialogFrag2` code?

Comment: @Bryan Here you go! http://pastebin.com/iJpzdXM7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you implement `ColorPickerDialogListener` for your `ViewHolder`, but looking through the code of library [here](https://github.com/danielnilsson9/color-picker-view/blob/master/color-picker-view/src/main/java/com/github/danielnilsson9/colorpickerview/dialog/ColorPickerDialogFragment.java#L90), you could see that it tries to cast `activity` as a `ColorPickerDialogListener`, otherwise it throws the exception. So try to implement this listener on your `MainActivity` and see the result.

**UPDATE:**

So in that case you need to change logic of your `ColorPickerDialogFrag2` to something like this:

```
...
private ColorPickerDialogListener mListener;

public static ColorPickerDialogFrag2 newInstance(ColorPickerDialogListener listener,
        int dialogId, int initialColor) {

    ColorPickerDialogFrag2 frag = new ColorPickerDialogFrag2();
    frag.setListener(listener);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("id", dialogId);
    args.putInt("init_color", initialColor);

    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}

public void setListener(ColorPickerDialogListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}
...

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (mListener == null) {
        // Check for listener in parent activity
        try {
            mListener = (ColorPickerDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassCastException("Parent activity must implement "
                    + "ColorPickerDialogListener to receive result.");
        }
    }
}
...
```

And then just pass `ColorPickerDialogListener` as a parameter to `newInstance` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    ColorPickerDialogFrag2 cp = ColorPickerDialogFrag2.newInstance(this, 6, Color.YELLOW);
    cp.setStyle(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);
    cp.show(fragmentManager,"d");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Allright good info! I know it works in MainActivity, but It must work in the adapater where the pre-defined buttons are. So when the user longclicks on one of the pre-defined buttons from the recyclerview, they can then change the color.

Comment: It worked as it should! Thanks. But could you explain why we had to pass its own listener to newInstance?

Comment: We do it cause we can make every object as listener, not only activity

Comment: It's not fragment's own listener, this is the listener from parameters